# Handling FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, methods, return

I am wondering if this is a good idea, or if it is better with a while loop around the initial call? Or something else?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] string = thisSameMethod(input);
}

public static String[] thisSameMethod(Scanner input){

  //Asking user for filename here

  try {
    //open and read file
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File Not found!\n Try again:");
    return thisSameMethod(input); //returning itself
  }
}
```

EDIT: How would this be instead?
make main like this, and put "return null" in the catch:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] string = null;
        while(string==null)
         string = thisSameMethod(input); 
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an error with the same name as this site, how ironic.

Comment: This is actually working though. I havent got any problems with this so far on my build at least.

Comment: I'm guessing it's being down voted because this code works, however badly. So it's a code review, rather than a fix.

Comment: It does work, but every time you go to `return thisSameMethod(input)` you are calling the function again, initializing another instance of all local variables, etc. It is inefficient compared to a while loop.

Comment: @RossDrew I don't see anything about questions asking about how to improve working code being off topic in: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Not specifically no, but phrases like "why they didn't work" & "describe the specific problem" refer mildly to problem code.  As well as that there is a specific forum, namely http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is obsolete if Stackoverflow functions as a code review site as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a terrible idea because it is an example of infinite recursion.  At a basic level, the following is a better solution:

```
public static String[] blammy(final Scanner input)
{
    boolean success = false;

    while (!success)
    {
        try
        {
            // stuff.
            success = true;
        }
        catch (FileNotFouncException exception)
        {
            // error stuff here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and remember to close your resources after use ;)

Answer (score 0):

No.  This will enter an infinite loop with thisSameMethod() recursively calling itself over and over until a valid file is entered and there are no errors opening it.

In this case it could also lead to a memory leak as the attempted file objects are never closed.  You need to close resources after an error, usually inside a finally block.

```
 try (File f = new File())
 {
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 }
 finally
 {
   f.close();
 }
```

The other option if you have Java 7 is to use a try-with-resources block.

```
 try (File f = new File())
 {
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 }
```

This will always close resources when you leave the scope of the try.  Which in your case would mean all file operations would need to be done inside your method as well.

Comment: Just want to add that actually ask the user for the file name in the start of thisSameMethod(), so it would be an infinite loop only if the user is never able to write a valid filename.

Still not a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. This will infinitely perform and call the operation; you'd either need to return nothing (so change this function to void) or as one has done above, use a loop and a boolean variable to stop it happening over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this snippet will do what you want,

```
public static class InvalidInputException extends Exception {

    public InvalidInputException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}

public static String[] getContentFromFile(String filePath)
        throws InvalidInputException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        // Read it to array

        return null;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new InvalidInputException("Erro!", e);
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close silently
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] fileContent = null;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please, input the file location!");
        String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            fileContent = getContentFromFile(nextLine);
        } catch (InvalidInputException e) {

            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("Something went wrong ");
            sb.append(e.getMessage());

            if (cause != null) {
                sb.append(" ");
                sb.append(cause.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    } while (fileContent == null);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] string = thisSameMethod(input);
}

public static String[] thisSameMethod(Scanner input){
   Scanner newInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  //Asking user for filename here

  try {
    //open and read file
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File Not found!\n Try again:");
    System.out.println("Please Enter Another file to look for: );
    String newFile = newInput.next();
    thisSameMethod(newInput);
  }
}
```